# Mule:Using HTTP operation based connector in Mule 3.5.2

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

I want to use HTTP operation based connector in mule version 3.5.2 for calling a rest service as having a requirement that instead of payload of mule message need to specify some property as request to HTTP connector which can be acheived by specifying source attribute.

Added maven dependency for mule http

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

and in flow.xml file included xml namespace

```
xmlns:httpn="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/httpn"  and 
xsi:schemaLocation="....
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/httpn http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/httpn/3.6/mule-httpn.xsd..."
```

Is it possible to use operation based connector in mule 3.5.2? Are there some other steps required apart from maven dependency and namespace in flow.xml as even after including namespace the flow is not able to include httpn namespace.If HTTP operation based connector is not possible to use what can i do to HTTP outbound endpoint connector so that http post request is mapped from a mule message property rather than payload and similar for response that response is returned to mule message property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing the HTTP transport and the HTTP module.

The HTTP module Maven dependency is actually:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-module-http</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Even after including maven dependency for mule-module-http and including httpn namespace in flow.xml  HTTP operation based connector is not available to me in flow(for a mule3.5.2 project). I want to use HTTP operation based connector as in endpoint connector payload is mapped to  request whereas my requirement is to map a flowVar as a request to connector. Is there a way to map HTTP outbound endpoint request to flowVars instead of payload.

Comment: The new HTTP module is for Mule 3.6 or above, not older versions of Mule.